# Market risk stress testing?

Tags: risk, statistics, research, value-at-risk, stress-testing

I am doing a research for a paper for market risk stress testing. In fact I found some information on the web about this important topic such as:

- [Stress Testing from Art to Science](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=https://homepages.fhv.at/tb/cms/?download=BreuerCsiszar-stresstest-v1.pdf&ei=UL7bUcSoL4Toswb-joGYBg&usg=AFQjCNG-H0izzlaeul-vRQfabYZR4w2h9w&sig2=WW4wqcCPYZ9UVD50nBNC8w&bvm=bv.48705608,d.Yms&cad=rja)
- [Stress Testing Value-at-Risk](http://www.jpmorgan.com/tss/General/Stress_Testing_Value-at-Risk/1159389400084)

However, this papers are mostly theoretical and do not talk about best practices or specific examples of market risk stress tests. I really would value a simple `R` example to understand the underlying calculations?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest ways is described in [Duffie, Pan (1997)](https://www.ime.usp.br/~rvicente/risco/duffie.pdf) "Bootstrapped Simulation from Historical Data" p.55.

$R$ is the set of all risk factors (a time series)
$C_{norm}$ is the Covariance Matrix during normal times.
$C_{stressed}$ is the Covariance Matrix from a period of stress.

You can update $R$ in the following way.

$R_{i,stressed}=C_{stressed}^{1/2}* C_{norm}^{-1/2}*R_{i,norm}$

This can be implemented in R in the following way:

```
Rstressed = Rnorm %*% solve(chol(cov(Rnorm))) %*% chol(cov(Rstressperiod))
```

Checking

```
cov(Rstressed)
cov(Rstressperiod)
```

will yield identical results.